# MVC WEB API Search Operation through multiple Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to perform a search operation. Somehow I've managed to implement the search operation for a column. Now I want to Search through multiple columns. for an example if my table contains the name, number, email, gender.
and if I search for word **M** and my **name** column contains a field as **Mandy** and if my **email** column contains as **man@mas.com** I want them both to be displayed.

How would I do this?

**view**

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @placeholder = "search by name" })</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="search" class="btn-success" /></td>
```

**MVC controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Customer cvm)
{
    CustomerClient cc = new CustomerClient();
    ViewBag.listCustomers = cc.search(cvm.name);
    return View();
}
```

**client Class:**

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> search(int name)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Base_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var result = client.GetAsync(string.Format("customers/search/{0}", name)).Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>().Result;
        return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**API Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search/{name}")]
public HttpResponseMessage search(int name)
{
    try
    {
        var httpresponsemessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        httpresponsemessage.Content = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.customers.Where(
            p => p.name.Contains(name)).ToList()));

        httpresponsemessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        return httpresponsemessage;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to add `OR` condition where you have managed to implement the search operation for `name` column?

Comment: Post your code! Is it stored procedure or anything that you have tried!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i have posted the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As assume, if you are using Query then try below one:

```
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
WHERE name LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR number LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR
      email LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR gender LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
```

If you are using EF then try below one,

```
db.customers.Where(p => p.name.Contains(name) || p.number.Contains(name)
                    || p.email.Contains(name) || p.gender.Contains(name)).ToList();
```